# Reading a textfile inside an sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an .sql file with a set of assignments and source files mentioned in it:
The file looks like below:

```
SET @NAME='ABC'
SOURCE c:/dev/test.sql
SOURCE c:/dev/test1.sql
.
.
.
SOURCE c:/dev/test100.sql

SET @NAME='MNO'
SOURCE c:/dev/test.sql
SOURCE c:/dev/test1.sql
.
.
.
SOURCE c:/dev/test100.sql
```

The files mentioned in the `SOURCE c:/dev/*` is repeating for each assignment using the SET command.

Is there a way by which I can read the file names from a different test file , so that i can avoid the redundancy of the code inside my .sql file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: First you need to decide which DBMS you are using. Surely you don't need this for mysql, sql server and oracle??? And even if you do the answers will be vastly different.

Comment: I am using mysql . Is there anyway to minimize the code? I have 100's of sqls as input to the `SOURCE ...`

Comment: Hopefully somebody will be able to help. I am a sql server guy and can't even spell mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

File: `/path/to/file/test.sql`

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('FROM test.sql @`NAME`: ', @`NAME`);
```

File: `/path/to/file/allTestFiles.sql`

```sql
SOURCE /path/to/file/test.sql
SOURCE /path/to/file/test1.sql
SOURCE /path/to/file/test2.sql
# .
# .
# .
# SOURCE /path/to/file/test100.sql
```

File: `/path/to/file/master.sql`

```sql
SET @`NAME` := 'ABC';
SOURCE /path/to/file/allTestFiles.sql

SET @`NAME` := 'MNO';
SOURCE /path/to/file/allTestFiles.sql
```

Test:

```sql
mysql> SOURCE /path/to/file/master.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('FROM test.sql @`NAME`: ', @`NAME`) |
+--------------------------------------------+
| FROM test.sql @`NAME`: ABC                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('FROM test1.sql @`NAME`: ', @`NAME`) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| FROM test1.sql @`NAME`: ABC                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('FROM test2.sql @`NAME`: ', @`NAME`) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| FROM test2.sql @`NAME`: ABC                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('FROM test.sql @`NAME`: ', @`NAME`) |
+--------------------------------------------+
| FROM test.sql @`NAME`: MNO                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('FROM test1.sql @`NAME`: ', @`NAME`) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| FROM test1.sql @`NAME`: MNO                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('FROM test2.sql @`NAME`: ', @`NAME`) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| FROM test2.sql @`NAME`: MNO                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```